# How to filter recent commands in shell?

Tags: command-line, windows-10

Say I have entered a lot of commands into the shell and now I want to enter a long one again.
I could just go up with the arrow-button on my keyboard, but since I know the word `--indent` was in that command, is there a way to do it quicker?

Answer (score 0):

No, natively Windows Command Line has no History. But Power Shell does if you have it installed. There is a  `history` command. To search for a line in your history

```
history | findstr "indent"
```

Alternatively you could use other (often better) Shells on Windows like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/).

**Edit:** 
And I also just found out about <kbd>F7</kbd>. It shows you a pop-up list of last used commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using powershell?  Install [PSReadline](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2015/04/28/use-psreadline-for-more-efficient-powershell-console.aspx).  Set it up to be part of your problem.  With that in place you should be able to use the CTRL-R and then start typing the most recent command that matches should be